# substract two date end return value

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I need help to build a query to substract two dates in mongodb.

I have some documents like above :

```
{"_id" : "32472034809", "center": "102030", dateArq : 141010, inDate : "ISODate("2014-06-06T02:57:19.000-03:00)", biDate : ISODate("2014-06-07T02:57:19.000-03:00)"}
```

And Im trying to write a query

```
db.teste.aggregation([{$match : {dateArq : 141010}},{$project : {$subtract : ["$biDate" "$inDate"]}}])
```

In fact, I want to do : for each _id I want to result biDate - inDate , because I need to see if  dateArq keep in a line constante.

In Oracle I did

```
select dateArq, (biDate - inDate) diff from teste where dateArq = 141010
```

Tks for help

Answer (score 1):

The document and aggregation pipeline provided had syntax problems, and you needed to put a field name for the result of the `$subtract`, but otherwise your pipeline works for me:

```
> db.test.findOne()
{
    "_id" : "32472034809",
    "center" : "102030",
    "dateArq" : 141010,
    "inDate" : ISODate("2014-06-06T05:57:19Z"),
    "biDate" : ISODate("2014-06-07T05:57:19Z")
}
> db.test.findOnedb.test.aggregate([
    { "$match" : { "dateArq" : 141010 } }, 
    { "$project" : { "dateDiff" : { "$subtract" : ["$biDate", "$inDate"] } } }
])
{ "_id" : "32472034809", "dateDiff" : NumberLong(86400000) }
```